# How to disable secure load for only one page

Tags: ssl, iis, https, url-rewriting

We have SSL 443 for www.allied.com, so all the web pages loads in https.
I want one particular page *not* to load in https.

Say for instance, I would want the below page
https://www.allied.com/international-moving-company/booking-customs
to load as 
http://www.allied.com/international-moving-company/booking-customs

How can I code this exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS 8.5 disable rewrite rule for virtual directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445929/iis-8-5-disable-rewrite-rule-for-virtual-directory)

Comment: Cleaned up wording and phrasing.